# How to change text of Label while typing in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Please I'm new to C#, I created a textBox and a label. What i am expecting is, if I type a value into the textBox, I want it to display on the label and if I change the value it should also change immediately on the label.
it work with the code below and i press enter key

```
 private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            label1.Text = textBox1.Text;
        }
   }
```

But I want it without press Enter/Return Key on keyboard.

Thanks for understanding

Comment: What type of project have you created? Winforms, WPF, Web, etc? The answer depends on what type of project you have.

Comment: Add your code, to see what you tried and what problem you have.

Comment: project on WindowsFormsApplication

Comment: You need an event handler to respond to the change in value in the text box that updates the label.  See the documentation of [`TextChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 7):

**This works for VisualStudio**

Select your `TextBox` in the Designer, go to the it's properties and click on the events (teh icon with the lightning). Then make a double click on the event that is called: `TextChanged`.

[image]

This creates a new function, that will always be called when the text of your `TextBox` changes. Insert following code into the function:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    label1.Text = tb.Text;
}
```

That's it.

Comment: i try to use conditional statement for the code.. but don't get it further, help me out . ` if(e.GetType == KeyPress.){ TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    label1.Text = tb.Text; } else { label1.Text = " "; }

Comment: I wonder what happened to databindings? Might be there for nothing!

Comment: @owebindex: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am working inventory... what i am doing is when the seller enter quantity of product, it multiply the quantity with price. if quantity erase, it should echo "NO QUANTITY"

Answer (score 4):

```
label.DataBindings.Add("Text", textBox, "Text");
```

Comment: @AlexanderPetrow spot on. Less code=>max result. This is the accepted answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

textbox KeyDown/Up/Press events may help.
For example

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text += e.KeyData.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Try to remove the text from the `textBox1`. What will happen?

Comment: I know what will happen. It's just a simple example, not working version.

Comment: Wrong example. You might be better off quoting right one.